# gerrit hooks - automatically push upstream for review

Tags: gerrit

Im trying to create a gerrit-hook to automatically push upstream. When a change is merged into a repo (example , the dev repo) I'd like to push upstream (to QA) for review.  I was trying to do something in the change-merged hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
log=/tmp/`basename $0`.log
echo Running $BASH_SOURCE
set | egrep GIT > $log
env > $log
region=`basename /repos/dev.git .git`
echo region=$region
[ $region == "dev" ] && git push -u ssh://user@host:29418/qa HEAD:refs/for/master 
echo $log
mailx -s $0 my@email.com < $log
```

*Not sure where to set the "git remote add upstream ssh://" bit so I tried the above.
*also are hooks global(not per repo)?

Answer (score 2):

First you should read the documentation provided on hooks.
Second, the hooks are not execute in the git directories. You need to use the GIT_DIR environment variable to access you git directory. 
Hooks are global and not per repo. But of course, that does not stop you from creating your own using something like $GIT_DIR/hooks/my_hook

Comment: The confirmation that the hooks are global and the idea to use $GIT_DIR to create hooks per repo are helpful. thanks.